# for loop over odd numbers in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to solve the task

> Using a standard for-in loop add all odd numbers less than or equal to 100 to the oddNumbers array

I tried the following:

```
var oddNumbers = [Int]()
var numbt = 0
for newNumt in 0..<100 {
    var newNumt = numbt + 1; numbt += 2; oddNumbers.append(newNumt)
}

print(oddNumbers)
```

This results in:

> 1,3,5,7,9,...199

My question is: Why does it print numbers above 100 although I specify the range between 0 and <100?

Comment: On a side note, this question illustrates the importance of variable naming. This question might well not exist if the code used meaningful variables names.

Answer (score 10):

You're doing a mistake:

```
for newNumt in 0..<100 {
    var newNumt = numbt + 1; numbt += 2; oddNumbers.append(newNumt)
}
```

The variable `newNumt` defined *inside* the loop does not affect the variable `newNumt` declared in the `for` statement. So the `for` loop prints out the *first 100 odd numbers*, not the *odd numbers between 0 and 100*.

If you need to use a `for` loop:

```
var odds = [Int]()
for number in 0...100 where number % 2 == 1 {
    odds.append(number)   
}
```

Alternatively:

```
let odds = (0...100).filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }
```

will filter the odd numbers from an array with items from 0 to 100. For an even better implementation use the `stride` operator:

```
let odds = Array(stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 2))
```

Comment: I would avoid the technique you show, in favour of using stride. It's pointless to make a list of N numbers, only to discard half of them

Comment: You're right. I didn't read the answer from @appzYourLife, `stride` definitely works better. Thanks for the note!

Comment: You want to start your stride at 1, not 0.  Also you can use stride in the for in loop as well `for number in stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 2) {`

Answer (score 4):

If you want all the odd numbers between 0 and 100 you can write

```
let oddNums = (0...100).filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }
```

or

```
let oddNums = Array(stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 2))
```

Comment: thanks man, i understand that my question is i put the range between 0 and 100 why is printing over that

Comment: @Slavo3 just put a break point in init and step through it. It'lll be a good learning exercise

Comment: Great explanation i understand know :) omg i need 3 days to figur-out

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it print numbers above 100 although I specify the range between 0 and <100?

Look again at your code:

```
for newNumt in 0..<100 {
    var newNumt = numbt + 1; numbt += 2; oddNumbers.append(newNumt)
}
```

The `newNumt` used inside the loop is different from the loop variable; the `var newNumt` declares a new variable whose scope is the body of the loop, so it gets created and destroyed each time through the loop. Meanwhile, `numbt` is declared outside the loop, so it keeps being incremented by 2 each time through the loop.

I see that this is an old question, but none of the answers specifically address looping over odd numbers, so I'll add another. The `stride()` function that Luca Angeletti pointed to is the right way to go, but you can use it directly in a `for` loop like this:

```
for oddNumber in stride(from:1, to:100, by:2) {
    // your code here
}
```

`stride(from:,to:,by:)` creates a list of any strideable type up to but not including the `from:` parameter, in increments of the `by:` parameter, so in this case `oddNumber` starts at `1` and includes `3, 5, 7, 9...99`. If you want to *include* the upper limit, there's a `stride(from:,through:,by:)` form where the `through:` parameter is included.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the odd numbers between 0 and 100 you can write

```
    for i in 1...100 {
    if i % 2 == 1 {
        continue
    }

    print(i - 1)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For **Swift 4.2**

```
extension Collection {
    func everyOther(_ body: (Element) -> Void) {
        let start = self.startIndex
        let end = self.endIndex

        var iter = start

        while iter != end {
            body(self[iter])

            let next = index(after: iter)
            if next == end { break }
            iter = index(after: next)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
class OddsEvent: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        (1...900000).everyOther{ print($0) } //Even
        (0...100000).everyOther{ print($0) } //Odds

    }
}
```

This is more efficient than:
**let oddNums = (0...100).filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }** or
**let oddNums = Array(stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 2))**
because supports larger Collections

Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/229/